I am having trouble uploading multiple files from my next 14 app to google cloud strorage
I've been having a lot of trouble trying to upload images from my next 14 to my Google Cloud bucket. I looked for different solutions but nothing works with next 14 and the next js API. I'm using
This is the next js code api/uploader/route.ts


import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID,
  credentials: {
    client_email: process.env.GCLOUD_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    private_key: process.env.GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY?.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
  },
});

const bucket = storage.bucket("bucket_name");

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const formData = await req.formData();
    const files = Array.from(formData.entries())
      .filter(([key, value]) => value instanceof File)
      .map(([key, value]) => value as File);

    if (files.length === 0) {
      console.log('No files uploaded');
      return NextResponse.json({ message: 'No files uploaded.' }, { status: 400 });
    }

    const uploadPromises = files.map(async (file) => {
      const buffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
      const blob = bucket.file(file.name);

      return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
          resumable: false,
        });

        blobStream
          .on('finish', () => {
            console.log(`Successfully uploaded ${file.name}`);
            resolve();
          })
          .on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(`Failed to upload ${file.name}:`, err);
            reject(err);
          });

        blobStream.end(Buffer.from(buffer));
      });
    });

    await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

    console.log('All files uploaded successfully');
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Files uploaded successfully!' });
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error('Error in API route:', error);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: `Upload failed: ${error.message}` }, { status: 500 });
  }
}



this is my frontend code


"use client"

import { useState } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';

const ImageUploader = () => {
  const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState<File[]>([]);
  const [uploadStatus, setUploadStatus] = useState<'idle' | 'uploading' | 'success' | 'error'>('idle');

  const handleImageChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const files = Array.from(event.target.files || []);
    setSelectedImages(files);
  };

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    setUploadStatus('uploading');
  
    const formData = new FormData();
    selectedImages.forEach((image) => {
      formData.append('images', image);
    });

    formData.forEach(data =>{
      console.log("data:", data)
    })
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/uploader', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      });
  
      if (response.ok) {
        setUploadStatus('success');
        setSelectedImages([]);
      } else {
        setUploadStatus('error');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      setUploadStatus('error');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Image Uploader</h1>
      <input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" onChange={handleImageChange} />
      <button onClick={handleUpload} disabled={selectedImages.length === 0 || uploadStatus === 'uploading'}>
        Upload
      </button>
      {uploadStatus === 'uploading' && <p>Uploading images...</p>}
      {uploadStatus === 'success' && <p>Images uploaded successfully!</p>}
      {uploadStatus === 'error' && <p>Error uploading images. Please try again.</p>}
      <div>
        {selectedImages.map((image, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <Image src={URL.createObjectURL(image)} alt={`Image ${index}`} width={200} height={200} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageUploader;




Blockquote
Failed to upload 444776562_1777029579372259_226178548914055971_n.jpg: NodeError: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed

the error I'm getting
